# making a Mysql table and I keep getting the same syntax error

Tags: mysql

Im very new to mysql and I keep getting the same error whenever i try to make a table

```
CREATE TABLE tasks {                                                     
   id INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
   description VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   completed TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   created DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
   last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()
};
```

I wanted it to make a table but instead I got:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '{
>
> ```
> id INT  NOT NULL PRIMA' at line 1
> ```

Comment: You can't use two `PRIMARY KEY` clauses on one column.. Also the `{` and `}` usage is wrong, check the MySQL manual about using [CREATE TABLE ..](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. `CREATE TABLE` uses parentheses not braces.

`CREATE TABLE foo`**(**`col1 int, col2 varchar(25), col3 timestamp`**)**`;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right syntax:

```
    CREATE TABLE tasks (id INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, description VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, completed TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, created DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(), last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW())
```